# Pass state dispatcher as a prop to child component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Can I pass state dispatcher (second arg from `useState`) as a prop to child component. Is it antipattern or allowable practice?

For example. I have a component `TextField`. I'm using it everywhere. And everyvere I need save its value to state. For example:

```
import { default as React, setState, useCallback } from 'react';
import { TextField } from '@component';

const SomeComponent = (props) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');

 const handleChange = useCallback((e) => setValue(e.target.value), []);

  return (
    <div>
      <TextField onChange={handleChange} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

I'm tired to write handleChange everywhere when `TextField` had used... I want make this case simpliest.

Can I pass `setValue` to TextField as a props (instead adding onChange) and implement setting value inside of TextField?

```
// ...
  <TextField valueDispatcher={setValue} />
//...
```

Comment: I see two separate questions here: 1. is it ok to pass `setValue` down though props? (I believe it's fine) 2. is it ok to introduce custom props with different logic instead of those based on standard DOM attributes like `onChange` or `onClick`? (I believe it will make affect maintainability)

Answer (score 1):

**Yes.**

You can pass `setValue` as props to child component. From child component you can set the value.

[Working Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandbox-5w1yb?fontsize=14)

Comment: Thanks for answer. I know that it works. But react doesn't recommended change state one component from other component. Do you think is this antipattern or not?

Comment: As per my understanding, there is no such rule / recommendation that you cannot change state of one component (to be more precise, parent component) from other component (child component).

Comment: React preaching lifting state, not changing state from child components..

Comment: And one more link
https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#the-data-flows-down

Comment: `lifting state up` is the concept when you have one parent and multiple child components. In each child component you have same state variable, in that case you need to up lift that state to parent component. This does not mean that you cannot change from child component.

Comment: Ok. What about second link and data flows down? Dut when we change parent's state from child component it isn't top-down. It's down-top ))

Comment: `data-flows-down` means you can only pass state to child component, you cannot pass child state to parent component as props. To pass data from child to parent you need pass a function from parent to child and using that function you can pass data from child to parent. As I did in my demo.

Comment: I also thought about dispatcher is function and passing function to child component isn't antipattern. But I still doubt because this function changes state of parent component...

Comment: It is not anti-pattern in any way. You can do this.